# Need to make a sharepoint field required programmatically

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using a standard sharpoint form, I have code that displays a tracking number once the user selects "completed" on the "Status" dropdown.  All of it functions, what i need to do at this point is make the tracking number required once they select completed.  If i make the field required via sharepoint and then try to hide it sharepoint will not save the task :/ Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
var statusField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Status');  
var showOrHideField = function() {
    var statusFieldValue = statusField.GetValue();       
    if(statusFieldValue != 'Appeal Mailed') {
        SPUtility.HideSPField('Tracking Number');
    }
    else 
    {              
      SPUtility.ShowSPField('Tracking Number');                            
    }
};
 showOrHideField();

$(statusField.Dropdown).on('change', showOrHideField);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple options:

**Option 1: List Validation Settings**

This can be accomplished non-programmatically using SharePoint 2010's list validation settings. (Go to List Settings -> Validation Settings.)

You can add an Excel-like formula that must resolve to true in order for an item to be considered valid.

In your case, the formula would look something like this:

`=IF([Status]="completed",NOT(ISBLANK([Tracking Number])),TRUE)`

**Option 2: Overwrite PreSaveAction()**

In JavaScript, you can overwrite the PreSaveAction() function on the edit form to perform a programmatic check before allowing the form to be submitted.

In the function, return `true` if everything looks good and you want the save to go through, or `false` to abort the save.

Example:

```
function PreSaveAction(){
    var statusField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Status');
    var trackingField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Tracking Number');
    var isValid = 
        statusField.GetValue() != "completed" ||
        trackingField.GetValue().length > 0;
     if(!isValid){
        alert("You must enter a tracking number.");
    }
    return isValid
}
```

Comment: they way that i have had to do this is to put a content editor on my "default new form" and my "default edit form"....should i put code you gave me in with the code i pasted or should i put that on the list.  i was wondering if there was a better way to do this besides the content editor method. thanks for your help by the way :)

Comment: In with your code should be fine. You should be able to override the PreSaveAction function in your script if you add your JavaScript via content editor web part on the bottom of the new and edit forms.

Comment: That worked!!! i got it...thank you so much, i tried the presave thing before but it didn't work for me, thank you for spelling it out.